# Heroku Application error Angularjs and Gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, gulp

I have install my webapp Angular in Heroku but don't work.
I try many solution that I find in internet, but without result.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "yoangular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-useref": "~3.0.3",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Heroku Logs

> 2017-10-05T19:54:38.573601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 134
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.573414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! yoangular@0.0.0 start: `npm start`
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.573866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.574111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the yoangular@0.0.0 start script.
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.574295+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.579163+00:00 app[web.1]: npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
>   2017-10-05T19:54:38.580016+00:00 app[web.1]:

Answer (score 0):

You only have **devDependencies** defined.

I think you need to define some regular **dependencies** for you app.

Usually devDependencies are only installed during dev and testing.

In production you install the **dependencies** modules.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies